# Can a subclass of Python class have different arguments than the Base Class?

Tags: python, inheritance

I am using Python 3.6.7 and I have:

```
class CodeModel:
    def tokenize(self, lexer, save_tokens=None):
        tokens = np.array([], dtype='object')
        line_count = 0
```

Then I have:

```
class JSCode(CodeModel):
    def tokenize(self, **kwargs):
        lexer = JavascriptLexer()
        super().tokenize(lexer, **kwargs)
```

Within the `CodeModel`, I have:

```
self.tokenize(save_tokens='stuff')
```

I want it to then call the `tokenize` of the `JSCode`, which doesn't need `save_tokens` and pass that to the base class, `CodeModel`.`tokenize`.

However, the way I'm doing it doesn't seem to work. The error I get is:

```
    self.tokenize(save_tokens=save_tokens)
TypeError: tokenize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'save_tokens'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have the `self.tokenize(save_tokens='stuff')` inside CodeModel and want it to call the tokenize of JSCode? That won't work since CodeModel has no idea that JSCode inherits from it - do you actually want `JSCode` to derive `CodeModel`?

Comment: maybe you need just super(CodeModel,self).tokenize(lexer, **kwargs)

Comment: You have a very valid point @SV-97. It makes sense that `CodeModel` doesn't know about `JSCode`. So perhaps I can just pass the arguments all the way directly? Instead of with `**kwargs`

Comment: @Shamoon well what are you actually trying to achieve in terms of functionality? Just want to rule out an XY problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `type(self)` is `CodeModel`, but you know you want to call the `JSCode.tokenize`, you can do that with `JSCode.tokenize(self)`

I can think of no good reasons why `self` should be of type `CodeModel` then. If the code doesn't need any other features of `JSCode`, why have it under that class anyway. Just have a method in the module namespace